# Why is my title bar not showing up in my Tkinter messagebox?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I'm working in VS Code with Python 3 and Tkinter on a Mac with Big Sur.  The title bar shows up on:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Password Manager")
```

But, for some reason, they're not showing up on my `messageboxes`:

```
messagebox.showwarning("Oops!", "Please don't leave any boxes empty.")
```

It's a basic program and I'm not sure if it's the code, VS Code, Python or some setting that I've inadvertently changed along the way.  Any help would be great!!

Window & message box screenshot:
[image: window & message box screenshot]

Here's my full code, for info:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import choice, randint, shuffle
import pyperclip

LABEL_FONT = "Adobe Gothic Std"

# ---------------------------- PASSWORD GENERATOR ------------------------------- #


def generate_password():
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

    password_list = [choice(letters) for char in range(randint(8, 10))]
    password_list += [choice(symbols) for char in range(randint(2, 4))]
    password_list += [choice(numbers) for char in range(randint(2, 4))]
    shuffle(password_list)

    password = "".join(password_list)
    password_entry.insert(0, password)
    pyperclip.copy(password)

# ---------------------------- SAVE PASSWORD ------------------------------- #


def save():
    website_name = website_entry.get()
    email_address = email_entry.get()
    new_password = password_entry.get()

    if len(website_name) == 0 or len(new_password) == 0:
        messagebox.showwarning("Oops!", "Please don't leave any boxes empty.")
    else:
        is_ok = messagebox.askokcancel(title=website_name, message=f"These are the details entered: \nEmail: {email_address} "
                                       f"\nPassword: {new_password} \nIs it ok to save?")
        if is_ok:
            with open("my_passwords.txt", "a") as data_file:
                data_file.write(f"{website_name} *|* {email_address} *|* {new_password}\n")
                website_entry.delete(0, END)
                password_entry.delete(0, END)


# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #
root = Tk()
root.title("Password Manager")
root.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(height=200, width=200)
logo_img = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_img)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)

# Labels
website_label = Label(text="Website:", font=(LABEL_FONT, 15))
website_label.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=E)

email_label = Label(text="Email/Username:", font=(LABEL_FONT, 15))
email_label.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=E)

password_label = Label(text="Password:", font=(LABEL_FONT, 15))
password_label.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=E)

# Entry Boxes
website_entry = Entry(width=37)
website_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, pady=5)
website_entry.focus()

email_entry = Entry(width=37)
email_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2, pady=5)
email_entry.insert(0, "designguru14-shoppie@yahoo.com")

password_entry = Entry(width=21)
password_entry.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W, pady=5)

# Buttons
password_button = Button(text="Generate Password", padx=5, pady=5, command=generate_password)
password_button.grid(column=2, row=3)

add_info_button = Button(text="Add", width=38, pady=5, command=save)
add_info_button.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like that window manager even has a title bar to put a title into. I'm not surprised there's no title.

Comment: It's some MacOS-related issue because on my Windows system the `messagebox` does have a title bar displaying `Oops!`. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLa35.png). A workaround would be to create your own message box based on a [`Toplevel`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/toplevel.html) widget.

Comment: Off-topic: When posting questions here, please only post a [mre]. The code in your question currently uses the third-party `pyperclip` module, which isn't related to the problem and is not required to reproduce it — so shouldn't have there at all.

Comment: It does appear to be a Mac OS issue. I am doing the same course that you are, on the same exercise, and I have the same issues you have. I am using PyCharm and not VS Code.  Not sure if you've experienced this, but in addition to having no title I get a warning in the console that reads: "2020-12-22 15:21:13.447 Python[97894:3214791] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSButton: 0x7fbcee72dbf0>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation." The error message displays once upon showing the message and once on dismissal.

Comment: Yes, Steve... same warning.  It's so weird that I cannot find anything out there about this.  My first thought was that it was something new to Big Sur, but I have no way of checking that.  If you find anything out, let me know.  Thanks!!

Comment: Dear community I am adding a comment to see if anyone is able to look at this question and maybe by now, they found an answer. thanks

Comment: @DrissLeo yes, there is an answer but you won't like it.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentations](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/messageBox.htm#M11) states that

> This option is ignored on Mac OS X, where platform guidelines forbid
> the use of a title on this kind of dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is how tkinter is implemented in Mac OS X. Try this code, which shows a title bar on my on my OpenBSD machine

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import messagebox

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tkinter
else:
    import tkinter
 
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('640x380')

messagebox.showwarning("Oops!", "I did it again")
window.mainloop()
```

I tested it on my Mac, this is the output I get:

[image]

- Darwin Kernel Version 17.7
- Python 3.8.3
- Tk 8.6

I tried your program on my Mac, the title bar shows in the message box. It's most likely a setting or version problem

[image: img]

Comment: I appreciate the help, but frankfm... this did not work for me.  I do agree with you, and the other comments, that it's something Mac related.  It's a little thing, but it's driving me crazy!!  :)

Comment: Which versions are you using of tkinter, Python?  You can check with `uname -a`, `python3 --version`, `python3 -m tkinter`.  Are you using any theme or skin on your mac?

Comment: I'm not using any special theme... just the default light theme.  Here's what else I have:    Darwin Kernel Version: 20.1, Python 3.9 & Tkinter 8.6.  Thanks for the help!!  I do think it's a setting somewhere, but I just cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually set the args `title` like:

```
messagebox.showwarning(title='Oops!', message="Please don't leave any boxes empty.")
```

Comment: Thanks, Molly.  I actually had them set up with the keyword args, but it still doesn't work.  It's gotta be a Mac thing... somehow.

Comment: You can put an issue in [vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues) to describe your question, and there will be engineers to solve it if it's a bug.